# file uploading multiple times in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

i am trying to upload files in codeigniter.but my files are uploading multiple times.this is my controller code.

```
 public function savedocument() {
            if (isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES)) {
                $category_id = $_POST['category'];
                $category_name = $_POST['category_name'];
                $config = array();
                $config['upload_path'] = 'uploadpath';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|doc|docx';
                $config['max_size']      = '20480';
                $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $files = $_FILES;
                for($i=0; $i< count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++)
                {           
                    $_FILES['files']['name']= $files['files']['name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['files']['type']= $files['files']['type'][$i];
                    $_FILES['files']['tmp_name']= $files['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['files']['error']= $files['files']['error'][$i];
                    $_FILES['files']['size']= $files['files']['size'][$i];    
    
                    $this->upload->initialize($config);
                            
                    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('files')) {
                        $response['message'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                    } 
                    else {           
                        $this->upload->do_upload('files');
                        $file_details = $this->upload->data();
                                            //print_r($file_details);
                        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
                        $uploaded_file_details = array(
                             'tmp_name' => $file_details["file_name"],
                            'file_name' => $file_details["orig_name"],
                            'size' => $file_details["file_size"],
                            'type' => $file_details["file_type"],
                            'category_name' => $category_name,
                            'category_id' => $category_id,
                            'upload_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                            'uploaded_by' => $user_id
                            ); 
                        $document_id = $this->document->CraeteNewDocument($uploaded_file_details);
                                            
                    } 
    redirect('admin/documents', 'refresh');                                
                }
            }
        }
```

can anyone point out the issue.how to make if there is only one file to upload upload it once and if multiple files are selected.have to upload it.

Comment: `if (!$this->upload->do_upload('files')) {` will do the upload - so if it works it runs it again in the else. I would do: `$result = $this->upload->do_upload('files');` and then test if $result is true/false

Comment: can you debug it with `print_r($_FILES);die;` before `for` loop?